# Get keys in multidimensional array in sorting method

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, indexing, key

I'm posting this topic because I wanted to know if it was possible to retrieve the keys of a multidimensional array in a sort method.

The structure of the table is as follows :

```
$array = Array();
$array['Key-1'] = Array('Element-1' => 'a', 'Element-2' => 'b', 'Element-3' => 'c', 'Element-4' => 'd');
$array['Key-2'] = Array('Element-1' => 'e', 'Element-2' => 'f', 'Element-3' => 'g', 'Element-4' => 'h');
$array['Key-3'] = Array('Element-1' => 'i', 'Element-2' => 'j', 'Element-3' => 'k', 'Element-4' => 'l');
$array['Key-4'] = Array('Element-1' => 'm', 'Element-2' => 'n', 'Element-3' => 'o', 'Element-4' => 'p');
```

For example, when I define a sort method, I can access the items *Element-1*, *Element-2*, *Element-3* and/or *Element-4*, in the variables **$a** and **$b**. What i wanted to know is if i could also access the upper keys : **Key-1**, **Key-2**, **Key-3** or **Key-4**.

```
function sortMethod($a, $b){
    => get here index key based on the item retrieved (Key-1, Key-2, ...)
}
usort($array, 'sortMethod');
```

Indeed, I need it because the sorting method must be based on these keys (**Key-1**, **Key-2**, ...) and also on the values (**Element-1**, **Element-2**, ...).

Like what we could do in a foreach loop when we specify :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}
```

Thanks for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You cas use `uksort()` and a **closure** to access to 1. array keys and 2. array values :

Eg. :

```
<?php

$array = [
    'Key-1' => ['Element-1' => 'a', 'Element-2' => 'b', 'Element-3' => 'c', 'Element-4' => 'd'],
    'Key-2' => ['Element-1' => 'e', 'Element-2' => 'f', 'Element-3' => 'g', 'Element-4' => 'h'],
    'Key-3' => ['Element-1' => 'i', 'Element-2' => 'j', 'Element-3' => 'k', 'Element-4' => 'l'],
    'Key-4' => ['Element-1' => 'm', 'Element-2' => 'n', 'Element-3' => 'o', 'Element-4' => 'p'],
];

uksort($array, function ($key_a, $key_b) use ($array) {
    echo "===================\r\n";
    echo "First key : {$key_a}, first element : ";
    print_r($array[$key_a]);
    echo "Second key : {$key_b}, second element : ";
    print_r($array[$key_b]);
    // ...
});
```

Gives :

```
===================
First key : Key-1, first element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => a
    [Element-2] => b
    [Element-3] => c
    [Element-4] => d
)
Second key : Key-2, second element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => e
    [Element-2] => f
    [Element-3] => g
    [Element-4] => h
)
===================
First key : Key-2, first element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => e
    [Element-2] => f
    [Element-3] => g
    [Element-4] => h
)
Second key : Key-3, second element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => i
    [Element-2] => j
    [Element-3] => k
    [Element-4] => l
)
===================
First key : Key-3, first element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => i
    [Element-2] => j
    [Element-3] => k
    [Element-4] => l
)
Second key : Key-4, second element : Array
(
    [Element-1] => m
    [Element-2] => n
    [Element-3] => o
    [Element-4] => p
)
```

- https://www.php.net/uksort
- https://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Have a good day!